# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'searchKeyword')

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass the `searchKeyword` parameter from the `SearchBar` component to the `Home` component using `useHistory` and `location.state`, but I'm stuck right now at the following error after restarting the program:

[image: this is the error image link]

This is my code:

```js
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState('');
  function handleChange(e) {
    setSearchKeyword(e.target.value);
  }
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.charCode == 13) {
      console.log(searchKeyword);
      history.push('/home', { searchKeyword: searchKeyword });

      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Search>
      <SearchIconWrapper>
        <SearchIcon />
      </SearchIconWrapper>
      <StyledInputBase
        placeholder="Search…"
        value={searchKeyword}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      />
    </Search>
  );
};
```

Home.js

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
  const location = useLocation();
  let loc = location.state.searchKeyword;
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCars = async () => {
      const res = await CarService.cardDisplayRequest();
      setCars(res.data);
      getCars().then((r) => r);
    };
  }, [cars]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography
        variant="h4"
        marked="center"
        align="center"
        component="div"
        sx={{ mt: 6, mb: 4 }}
      >
        <img src={CarImage} alt="old car" width="100%" height="50%" />
      </Typography>
      <Container component="section" sx={{ mt: 8, mb: 4, mr: 20, ml: 20 }}>
        <Box sx={{ mt: 8, display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
          <Container sx={{ mr: 20, ml: 20 }}>
            <Typography
              marked="center"
              align="center"
              variant="h2"
              component="h2"
              sx={{ fontWeight: 500, fontFamily: 'B' }}
            >
              Find your car
            </Typography>
            <div>
              <Typography
                marked="center"
                align="center"
                variant="h6"
                component="h6"
                sx={{
                  fontWeight: 500,
                  fontFamily: 'B',
                  borderBottom: '10px solid #c8d8e4',
                }}
              >
                Explore the world's best car sharing marketplace
              </Typography>
            </div>
          </Container>

          <Cards keywordParam={loc} />

          <FAQ />
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using [`react-router`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) here yes? If so then have a look at the example here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem